# Technique on how to format/color NSTextView's string

Tags: cocoa, string-formatting, nstextview, nsattributedstring

I'm looking for a reliable technique to do simple string formatting(bold, italic,...) in a NSTextView. The text parsing is almost done with regex, but now I need to apply font trait and also change the size.

Some code snippets on how I make a text bold

```
[[textView textStorage] beginEditing];
[[textView textStorage] applyFontTraits:NSFontBoldTrait range:range];
[[textView textStorage] endEditing];
```

This and also the size changes with

```
[[textView textStorage] beginEditing];  
NSFont* font = [[textView textStorage] attribute:NSFontAttributeName atIndex:range.location effectiveRange:nil];

NSFont* newFont = [NSFont fontWithName:[font familyName] 
                                  size:[font pointSize] + size];

[[textView textStorage] addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName 
                               value:newFont 
                               range:range];
[[textView textStorage] endEditing];
```

works fine. The only problem I have now is that in some cases, when I type new characters, those characters are bold or italic by default, even though I don't apply the properties to them.

Do I have to reset something with the `setTypingAttributes` of the `NSTextView` or do I simply miss something here?

Comment: I need to do something similar. Would you mind saying where you invoke the formatting code? In my case, I have a text view which uses a binding, so it could be modified either through editing or through a change done by the underlying controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right with the approach to set `typingAttributes`. [Reference for `-setTypingAttributes:` says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/setTypingAttributes%3a)

> However, if you add any user actions that change text attributes, the action should use this method to apply those attributes afterwards. User actions that change attributes should always set the typing attributes because there might not be a subsequent change in selection before the next typing.

That seems to apply in your case.

I don't know if the described behaviour is only correct for WYSIWYG editors like TextEdit. You seem to work on something that is similar in behaviour to an editor with syntax highlighting. There you never really want to change text attributes manually, but rather on structure from a grammar. It probably doesn't fit in that case, and you should reset `typingAttributes` or set it according to parsing up to there.

Comment: Since the effect was not reproduce able on my side, I think reseting the `typingAttributes` is the way to go. I will come back to this answer and mark it as correct when I could verify it.

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. I use the `textViewDidChangeSelection:` method from `NSTextViewDelegate` to hook in and call `setTypingAttributes:`. Tell me if it doesn't work, then I'll post the example project somewhere.

Comment: Here is a gist with the example: git://gist.github.com/1816087.git Type test, make it bold using the button, place the cursor inside a cold range, type, and it is plain font weight.